# Obtengo dos valores distintos al convertir un String a SHA1

Tags: java, sha1

Tengo el siguiente código con el cual estoy probando como encriptar contraseñas con SHA1. He usado código adaptado de dos fuentes distintas pero ambas me traen resultados distintos.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class Encriptacion 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String password = "Lucas";

        try 
        {
            //da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
            md.update(password.getBytes(), 0 , password.length());
            System.out.println(new BigInteger(1, md.digest()).toString(16));

            //CBEDE02E8C227684972AB1467409D98C0D0D5A5D
            MessageDigest msdDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
            msdDigest.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, password.length());
            password = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(msdDigest.digest());
            System.out.println(password);

        } 
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR : ");
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }

    }

}
```

Desconozco cual es el motivo por el cual me trae resultados distintos ni cual es la forma correcta de encriptar una contraseña.

Comment: Que raro? he probado el codigo y devuelve resultados similares salvo la diferencia que una devuelve el string en minusculas y la otra en mayusculas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ambos son métodos correctos y válidos:

I)

```
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
    md.update(password.getBytes(), 0 , password.length());
    System.out.println(new BigInteger(1, md.digest()).toString(16));
```

II)

```
    MessageDigest msdDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
    msdDigest.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, password.length());
    password = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(msdDigest.digest());
    System.out.println(password);
```

Puedes usar ambos métodos, ambos son correctos, en el caso de tu pregunta, si se encuentran en el mismo método únicamente asegura que al llamar cada uno debes inicializar tu variable:

```
password = "Lucas";
```

de esta forma obtendrás el resultado deseado.

---

**En cuanto al resultado `da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709` que estas obteniendo, la razón es que el valor de `password`  es un String vació "".**