# ¿Como obtener el SHA1 y SHA256 desde codigo?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy intentando obtener el SHA1 y el SHA256 desde código con java, esto lo voy a usar para autentificar de donde proviene la información para guardar en DB, entonces quiero obtener el SHA1 y SHA256 para enviar el dato, ahora lo tengo guardado en un String pero la idea es obtener los datos a la hora en que se ejecuta y no tener una variable registrada, esto para evitar que alguien decopile mi app y obtenga la clave que si se acepta

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el mètodo definido en esta pregunta:

[Obtengo dos valores distintos al convertir un String a SHA1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/102055/obtengo-dos-valores-distintos-al-convertir-un-string-a-sha1)

```
    String valor = "jorgesys"; 

    MessageDigest msdDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
    msdDigest.update(valor.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, valor.length());
    valor = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(msdDigest.digest());
    System.out.println(valor);
```

**Pero es muy importante mencionar que al convertir a SHA1 o SHA256 no podràs descifrar un valor generado por el algoritmo ya que es un hash unidireccional seguro.**

Si deseas un mecanismo de encriptaciòn como **AES**, revisa de la documentaciòn oficial:

[Trabaja con datos de forma más segura](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data)